# Logging Events from any database

Tags: sql-server

On an **Microsoft SQL Server 2014**
I want to make an stored procedure in the master database, which inserts some data in a table in a database located on the same server, lets call that database **EventLog** and the table **Event**.
The Stored Procedure on the master database has been marked as an system procedure using the `sp_MS_marksystemobject`.

**->** Now here the issue, I wan't all users known to the sql server to be able to insert data into the table, without having to add the server login to the database as an login.
First I thourght I could do something with the server role `Public`. but thats not working for me or i'm doing it wrong.

I tried enabling the `guest` user on the **EventLog** database and that makes it work for inserting, but that also shows the database and all of its objects, to any user on the server, which is not what i want.

Basicly I want to have an database, which can only be accessed to through the procedures in the `master` database, no matter which user you are. (implied that you can login on the server).

Is this possible???

Comment: Personally I would put the stored procedure inside EventLog rather than monkeying around with master/undocumented procedures, add all users to a LogWriter role & grant that execute permissions on the procedure.

Comment: Yes - why must you use master if you have already created another custom database to be used?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The reason why i want to have the procedures in master is so that the procedure can be called from any database.

Comment: @AlexK. then im not able to call the procedure when im in another database.

Comment: `exec dbname.schemaname.procedurename 'hello'`

Comment: If it's in master you call `exec myproc`. If it's in Eventlog then you call `exec Eventlog.dbo.myproc`. They're both hardcoded - not much difference

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid But you're still able to see the EventLog Database, which i dont want the user to know about, and all users has to be present in the EventLog database, which i dont want to add each time a new user is added to the server. What im trying to do here, is to make an centralized call to and Stored Procedure which logs information.
Also, i dont want to add stored procedures to all databases on the server.

Comment: _all users has to be present in the EventLog database_ this is also the case for master; _ i dont want to add each time a new user is added to the server_ this is also the case for master, but anyway you should probably be using windows AD groups, not adding individual users. _I dont want to add stored procedures to all databases on the server._ You'd only be adding it to EventLog, not all databases. The only thing I can't argue is _I dont want the user to know about_. Anyway now we have tried to convince you not to put custom things in master that's OK.

Comment: Perhaps have a read of this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1782/understanding-cross-database-ownership-chaining-in-sql-server/. You want a login to execute a proc in master which in turn has insert rights on a different db. I believe you need _cross database ownership chaining_ for this. I've never implemented this before but yes it looks like you need to enable guest in EventLog database

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid another reason why i want this to be located in the master, is that when i call the store procedure, i add information like DB_ID(), this will change depending which database your call the proc from, whereas, when you call it by 'dbname.schemaname.procedurename' the DB_ID() always return that same id, the id of the database its located in. Perhaps your right, maybe ownership chaining is the way to go, i just dont like it like that. but i will have to look into it, and see if it works for me. thanks mate.